# Operator returning incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, operators

```
var bedTime = $("bedtime").value;
var wakeUp = $("wakeup").value;

var Value = bedTime < wakeUp; 
alert("is " + bedTime + " less than " + wakeUp + '?  ' + Value);
```

My goal here to take user input through an html form (numeric only). This is what I wrote when I started running into the issue. Anything less than 10 except 1 will return the correct value, but anything over is incorrect. For example if bedTime = 10 and wakeUp = 9 it returns true. So just plugging in a few numbers leads me to believe that when comparing variables this way it only compares the first digit? Any workarounds? Thanks guys.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve.. be more specific with question please.. These details aren't enough to understand..

Comment: have you tried doing type(bedTime) and type(wakeUp)? What are the types returned if so...

Comment: Are you comparing strings instead of numbers?

Comment: "10" < "9" will yield true

Comment: var Value = +bedTime < +wakeUp;  maybe you want this?

Comment: be more specific. does this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9seap7w5/) represent your situation?

Comment: You need to cast to int. For example `parseInt(bedTime,10) < parseInt(wakeUp,10)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply's everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to make sure you are comparing the same type of data.

```
var Value = parseInt(bedTime) < parseInt(wakeUp);
```

Comparing strings is different, for example `'10' < '9' => true`.

Comment: Just one point - you should supply the radix when `parseInt` - so `parseInt(bedtime,10)` for example.

Comment: Why `parseInt()` at all when `Number()` does exactly what it says it will?

Comment: @lucas: The only reason I prefer `parseInt()` is because `Number('10F') => Nan`, while `parseInt('10F') => 10`

Comment: `parseInt()` isn't some magical alternative to form validation. 'F10' will get you NaN with either method - silently guessing what the user may have meant when the input is obviously a typo is just reckless imo, but your reason for using parseInt in the first place doesn't apply if OP has numeric-only fields

Comment: parseInt() worked I just had to declare ' bedTime = parseInt(bedTime); ' etc for others. Also I set the HTML field to ' type="number" ' as well thanks @lucas.